# Outbound audio issues with Asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I am running Asterisk 16.9.0 on a CentOS server at a client's location. That server connects via a SIP trunk provided by the telco.

I configured Zoiper on a couple of PC's there and connecting using IAX works for inbound & outbound calls. For some reason, connecting via SIP was giving audio problems. Now, calls from ext to ext, ext to outside and incoming calls are working fine without issues.

Now I am trying to connect to this server from my PC at my office. No VPN; port 5060 has been forwarded from the client's firewall.

From Zoiper, I connect using IAX, console shows as client registered. I can dial outside number and hear the called party fine. The called party hears a highly distorted version of my voice.

Using a Grandstream GXP1625, the console shows that a SIP client has connected. Dialing out, I can hear the called party, but he hears no sound and the call disconnects after 60 seconds.

What should I check / change?

```
Connected to Asterisk 16.9.0 currently running on server2 (pid = 2733)
    -- Registered SIP '1001' at xx.xx.xx.xx:61548
    -- Unregistered SIP '1001'
    -- Registered IAX2 '1001' (UNAUTHENTICATED) at xx.xx.xx.xx:4569
    -- Accepting UNAUTHENTICATED call from xx.xx.xx.xx:4569:
    --        > requested format = opus,
    --        > requested prefs = (),
    --        > actual format = gsm,
    --        > host prefs = (gsm|ilbc|speex|g729|g723|ulaw|alaw|g726|g726aal2|adpcm|slin|slin16|lpc10|speex16|g722|siren7|siren14|testlaw|g719|opus...),
    --        > priority = mine
    -- Executing [x-Called num-x@test:1] Set("IAX2/1001-3187", "CALLERID(num)=99222333") in new stack
    -- Executing [x-Called num-x@test:2] Dial("IAX2/1001-3187", "SIP/x-Called num-x@ntc-out") in new stack
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Called SIP/x-Called num-x@ntc-out
    -- SIP/ntc-out-0000001b is ringing
    -- SIP/ntc-out-0000001b is making progress passing it to IAX2/1001-3187
    -- SIP/ntc-out-0000001b answered IAX2/1001-3187
    -- Channel SIP/ntc-out-0000001b joined 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <f874b82d-74f3-430f-8475-2ea62dec3ff6>
    -- Channel IAX2/1001-3187 joined 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <f874b82d-74f3-430f-8475-2ea62dec3ff6>
    -- Channel SIP/ntc-out-0000001b left 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <f874b82d-74f3-430f-8475-2ea62dec3ff6>
    -- Channel IAX2/1001-3187 left 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <f874b82d-74f3-430f-8475-2ea62dec3ff6>
  == Spawn extension (test, x-Called num-x, 2) exited non-zero on 'IAX2/1001-3187'
    -- Hungup 'IAX2/1001-3187'
    -- Unregistered IAX2 '1001' (UNAUTHENTICATED)

    -- Registered SIP '1001' at xx.xx.xx.xx:53486
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Executing [x-Called num-x@test:1] Set("SIP/1001-0000001d", "CALLERID(num)=99222333") in new stack
    -- Executing [x-Called num-x@test:2] Dial("SIP/1001-0000001d", "SIP/x-Called num-x@ntc-out") in new stack
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Called SIP/x-Called num-x@ntc-out
    -- SIP/ntc-out-0000001e is ringing
    -- SIP/ntc-out-0000001e is making progress passing it to SIP/1001-0000001d
    -- SIP/ntc-out-0000001e answered SIP/1001-0000001d
    -- Channel SIP/ntc-out-0000001e joined 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <57e8fc55-7721-4465-840c-3d37bc76329c>
    -- Channel SIP/1001-0000001d joined 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <57e8fc55-7721-4465-840c-3d37bc76329c>
[Mar 17 22:13:26] WARNING[2978]: chan_sip.c:4126 retrans_pkt: Retransmission timeout reached on transmission 187fd4970375442eafe988f72e7ce772 for seqno 413 (Critical Response) -- See https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Retransmissions
Packet timed out after 31999ms with no response
[Mar 17 22:13:26] WARNING[2978]: chan_sip.c:4150 retrans_pkt: Hanging up call 187fd4970375442eafe988f72e7ce772 - no reply to our critical packet (see https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Retransmissions).
    -- Channel SIP/1001-0000001d left 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <57e8fc55-7721-4465-840c-3d37bc76329c>
    -- Channel SIP/ntc-out-0000001e left 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <57e8fc55-7721-4465-840c-3d37bc76329c>
  == Spawn extension (test, x-Called num-x, 2) exited non-zero on 'SIP/1001-0000001d'
    -- Unregistered SIP '1001'
```

*EDIT*
Looking at the log, I see that with a SIP connection it is a network issue as the server can't send packets back to my client PC.
So, I connected to the client's LAN via VPN and changed the connection address on my client from the firewall's external IP to the Asterisk server's LAN IP. Same result.

**EDIT**
sip.conf for telco line. That line is connected to server's second network port.

```
[telco]
type=friend
description=Telco
context=from-telco
externip = 10.12.15.222 <-- My server's 2nd port IP
localnet = 10.12.15.224/29
host=10.12.15.225  <-- telco's IP
media_address =10.12.15.226
permit=10.12.15.224/29
username=
fromuser=
secret=
insecure=invite
canreinvite=yes
qualify=yes
dtmfmode=rfc2833
allow=ulaw,alaw,gsm
nat=no
```

users.conf:

```
[101]
type=peer
username=clientpc
callerid="Client PC" <101>
secret=123123123
context=test
host=dynamic
qualify=yes
allow=all
nat=no

[1001]
type=peer
callerid="My office" <1001>
username=hussain
password=111222333
context=test
host=dynamic
allow=all
qualify=yes
nat=force_rport,comedia
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read more about networks and NAT traversal

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-sip-nat/

Comment: Read it. Seems straight forward enough though I am obviously missing something. On local net where the server is installed, ext-to-ext works fine. Ext-to-landline used to work, but is messed up now. From remote LAN (my office), Zoiper to client-LAN-ext = no sound both ways. Grandstream-to-client-LAN-ext, I can hear on the GS but other party can't. Sigh! I'll edit my question and put in excerpt from sip.conf and users.conf.

Comment: Debug is offtopic here. Nobody will debug your setup instead of you. Do sip set debug on and rtp set debug on and see what exactly happens. Use wireshark on phone's location.

Comment: External address CAN'T be in local network. It is impossible setup.

Comment: Sure, arheops. I am not expecting nor asking anyone else to do my work for me. What I am looking for is, as you mentioned, that there is a command "sip set debug". Didn't know about it, so, shall try that and see what happens. Yes, I had figured out that I was wrong in putting the externip setting there and have removed it. Also figured out the issue with Zoiper and have fixed it.